# How to restore an old WSL vhdx file

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I backed up an Ubuntu 20.04 `vhdx` file and did a computer cleanup.

I would like to get the files in the `vhdx` or mount the file again.

I tried reinstalling the same distribution on my Windows and replaced the newly created `ext4.vhdx` with the former one in my `localstate` directory.

But it says the file cannot be read.

Edit : I was running the wrong file. Just replacing the good one in the folder worked.

Comment: Good to hear you got it figure out.  I’m going to vote to close this question because it was due to a typo or user-error that isn't likely to help other users.  If you happen to spot this, feel free to delete the this question.  But if you do have future questions, feel free to ask (or answer!).